# Browser-sync - serve "node_modules" out of "src" directory

Tags: browser-sync, lite-server

I'm using browsersync via lite-server, and have the following configuration:

```
{
    "port": 8000,
    "files": [
        "./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"
    ],
    "server": {
        "baseDir": "./src",
        "routes": {
            "node_modules": "../node_modules" <--- Attempt to serve node_modules
        }
    }
}
```

Project layout is like this:

`node_modules
 src
  |-app
  |-index.html
  |-systemjs.config.js
 package.json
 bs-config.json`

The problem is that inside `index.html` any reference like
`<script src="node_modules/....js">` fails with a 404.

### How can I serve paths outside of .src directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expose whole project folder by adding one more element to baseDir as Edvin mentioned.

But it would be better if you will expose only `/node_modules` using routes:

```
module.exports = {
    server : {
        baseDir : './dist',
        routes : {
            '/vendor' : './node_modules'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple directory in baseDir config:

```
{
    "server": {
        "baseDir": ["./", "./src" ]
    }
}
```